# How to css menu have slash

Tags: html, css, styles

[image]

I want to make css to create menu like before. How to css?

Any idea. Thank so much.

Comment: You could use the same model as mentioned in the linked thread and just reverse the skew angle (as the skew is in a different direction in your image).

Comment: You can use pseudo elements like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/285/